# How do I update the text in label widget within the for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make a simple program that updates the text in the label in every iteration of `for` loop. I want the text to display **'0','1','2','3' and '4'** but the text directly shows the value **'4'**. How do I get my code show this transition.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class loop(App):
    def build(self):
       b = BoxLayout()
       btn = Button(text='start')
       btn.bind(on_press = self.start)
       b.add_widget(btn)

       self.label = Label(text='0')
       b.add_widget(self.label)

       return b

    def start(self,event):
       for i in range(5):
          self.label.text = str(i) #Change the text in every iteration

root  = loop()
root.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use sleep or while or for to update and widget in kivy instead kivy provides you with the clock method that will be very useful in this situations
simple the clock method will allows you to call any method you want in any time you want and here a simple example that will update the label text every one second but you can change that by changing the second argument of the lock method

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class loop(App):
    # creating a NumericProperty with 1 as initial value
    i = NumericProperty(1)

    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout()
        btn = Button(text='start')
        btn.bind(on_press=self.start)
        b.add_widget(btn)

        self.label = Label(text='0')
        b.add_widget(self.label)

        return b

    def start(self, *args):
        # testing if i is smaller than 5 or any other require number
        if self.i < 5:
            self.label.text = str(self.i)  # Change the text every time we call this method
            # increasing the app NumericProperty i by one
            self.i += 1
            # using the clock method to call back the start method once after reaching this line with one second
            Clock.schedule_once(self.start, 1)


root = loop()
root.run()
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to achieve the same result without the clock function? Any other ways??? Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Is it possible for me to get the same results without using the clock function?

Comment: no kivy provide this method to such things and there is a different ways to use the clock method see this https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html